# An error when use gulp and babelify?

Tags: gulp, browserify, babeljs

This is my gulp file

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('build', function () {
    return browserify({entries: 'main.js', extensions: ['.js'], debug: true})
    .transform(babelify)
    .bundle()
    .on("error", function (err) { console.log("Error : " + err.message); })
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['build'], function () {
    gulp.watch('main.js', ['build']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Here is my main.js

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

There is an error:unexcepted token (5:2) while parsing file main.js.
I have checked my code serveral times, still don't know why?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to run this command below and change `gulp.task()` method to below.

`npm i babel-preset-react`

```
gulp.task('build', function () {
    return browserify({entries: 'main.js', extensions: ['.js'], debug: true})
    .transform(babelify.configure({
        presets: ["react"]
}))
    .bundle()
    .on("error", function (err) { console.log("Error : " + err.message); })
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: It works.Thanks.I The point is to add config `presets:["react"]`